# When this error occurs Error:(1, 1) java: module JavaFX reads package java.awt from both java.desktop and java.datatransfer

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-11, module-info

**project name-JavaFX**
**module-info.java**

```
module JavaFX {
requires javafx.fxml;
requires javafx.controls;
requires java.desktop;
opens sample;
```

}

**Controller.java**

```
package sample;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;

import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

public class Controller {

    @FXML
    public void handleClick(){
        try{
            Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("http://www.javafx.com"));
        } catch (URISyntaxException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Error i get : Error:(1, 1) java: module JavaFX reads package java.awt from both java.desktop and java.datatransfer
How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just had the same problem. According to [This IDEA Support Thread](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360001344160-JavaFX-11-Module-Info-java-Issue) it may be somewhat of a red herring error message. It looks like the module file is actually correct (even though intellij takes you there), yet the problem is actually because IDEA adds a compiler parameter with all the alt-enter's we did (we all do it...).

If you navigate to settings -> Build, execution, deployment -> compiler -> Java compiler and look towards the bottom, you will see that its has added and --exports of awt from datatransfer to the module, as shown in the image below:

[image: Idea settings box]

Simple remove this and awt is only read from desktop.

I understand this problem isnt the most in depth explanation of whats going on, so if anyone would like to elaborate it would be mush appriciated.

Comment: Thanks for your help! That solves the issue but still why this happens?

Comment: no problem, I think its just one of the things that can happen when you alt-enter of a bit of red in intellij, specifically imports.